# Disable `Edit` option in a review task when edit queue is full

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, edits

I just earned (and learned about) Reviewer privileges. One of the options when reviewing is "Edit". On a recent review task (a first question) I chose the "Edit" option, but when I clicked "Save edits" on this particular post, I was made aware that the edit queue is full for this post.

---

Wouldn’t it make sense to notify the reviewer beforehand that the edit queue is full? What if they waste time making extensive edits only be denied by a full edit queue.

Comment: I've been getting the 'Suggested edit queue is full' error for the past day or two no matter what time I try. There might be some backend issues going on.